# Add object to a collection, call it from another class?

Tags: java, maven, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to take an object I have created with user input and put it into a collection, so that this can be called in another class.

I tried to create an ArrayList, but I only got a value of false returning.

Here is my code for the object

```java
Chair chairOrder = new Chair();
chairOrder.setFurnitureID(furnitureID); //Set the furnitureID input by the user

if (oakWood.isSelected()) {
    chairOrder.setWoodType(Furniture.WoodType.Oak); //Set the woodType to Oak
} else if(walnutWood.isSelected()) {
    chairOrder.setWoodType(Furniture.WoodType.Walnut); //Set the woodType to Walnut
}

chairOrder.setArmrestsOn(addArmrests.isSelected());//Checks to see if the checkbox for armrests is checked, if it is, armrests are added to the order
```

I want to be able to call this in another class to create a JLabel that allows me to have an image that when clicked, will display the information of this object.

Comment: Where is the ArrayList? What return the false value? You don't show enough code.

Comment: I removed the ArrayList because it was returning the false value of armrests not being added to the object of chairOrder.

I had the code as:

ArrayList<Chair> chairs = new ArrayList<Chair>();
                chairs.add(chairOrder);

Calling it anywhere would result it in priting out false.

Comment: maybe your problem is there, Can you show how you add the object to the arraylist and who calls the code you are showing.

Comment: The ArrayList is in the same class as the object (Chair class), I'm trying to be able to use the objects details to create a label in another class (OrderListing). 

I can't seem to get the ArrayList to even return false anymore, as my IDE can't access it in the OrderListing class. 

I don't quite understand how to show it to you, other than adding you to my GitHub repo for it.

Comment: Your `List` has to be in a different class.  The `Chair` class represents one chair.  You create another class, say `Furniture`, that holds a `List` of `Chair` instances.